# Finding an explicit word in a list using python

Tags: python, csv, parsing

I have a key-value (ID, tag) formatted CSV file containing the following:

1,art

2,fine art;masterpiece

3,modern art

4,artifact;artefact

5,article

My goal is to use python to return only IDs 1, 2, and 3, which are the tags with the word "art" explicitly within them. When I use the find() function (myfile.find("art")), it finds IDs 1-5.

My first thought was to look to the characters around the string "art" in the tags.  Maybe I could use the isalpha() function to ask if the character before and after the string "art" are indeed letters, not punctuation. However, this is one of the first python scripts I have written, so there may very well be a REGEX that does this in one line that I am not aware of.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) with a `\b` assertion:

```
>>> import re
>>> pairs = ((1, "art"), (2, "fine art;masterpiece"), (3, "modern art"),
             (4, "artifact;artefact"), (5, "article"))
>>> [id for id, tag in pairs if re.search(r"\bart\b", tag)]
[1, 2, 3]
```

As explained in the docs, `\b` matches a *boundary* between a 'word' and a 'non-word' character (or vice versa), or between a word character and the beginning/end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

You need to build a lookup index which implements your indexing logic. Read your file, parse each CSV line, and update a lookup index based on a `dict` for example. Each item in the lookup index should be normalized, lower case for example, and points to a list of IDs.

Here is a small snippet:

```
from StringIO import StringIO

file_content = StringIO('''1,art
2,fine art;masterpiece
3,modern art
4,artifact;artefact
5,article''')

_index = {}

for line in file_content:
    # parse CSV
    (_id, _, tags) = line.strip().partition(',')


    # parse tags
    tags = tags.split(';')

    tokens = set([])

    # tokenize tags
    for tag in tags:
        for token in tag.split(' '):
            # add normalized token to tokens set
            tokens.add(token.lower())

    # update index
    for token in tokens:
        if token in _index:
            _index[token].append(_id)
        else:
            _index[token] = [_id]

# lookup tag arg in your index
print _index['art']

>>> ['1', '2', '3']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
lines = ['art', 'fine art;masterpiece', 'modern art', 'artifact;artefact', 'article']
for l in lines:
    lis = [_.split(' ') for _ in l.split(';')] # Split the values.
    lis = [item for sublist in lis for item in sublist] # Flatten the list.
    print 'art' in lis # Check if 'art' is contained.
```

This allows you to determine the lines in which art (and not artifact) is containted. Or like this:

```
lines = ['art', 'fine art;masterpiece', 'modern art', 'artifact;artefact', 'article']
idx = 1
for l in lines:
    lis = [_.split(' ') for _ in l.split(';')] # Split the values.
    lis = [item for sublist in lis for item in sublist] # Flatten the list.
    if 'art' in lis: # Check if 'art' is contained.
        print idx
    idx = idx + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple and Sweet : use \b - Word Boundaries

```
a = ['1,art','2,fine art;masterpiece','3,modern art','4,artifact,artefact','5,article']
for data in a:
    output = re.search(r'\bart\b',data)
    if 'art' in str(output):
       ids = re.findall('\d+', data)
       print(ids)
```

Comment: Wow, harsh to downvote this answer but its actually quite a duplicate of eugene y's answer... maybe because of that someone downvoted...